# Ajax success function not waiting on internal script to complete before leaving scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this chunk of code:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  async: true,
  url: "Notes/ViewAttachments.aspx/CompressFiles",
  data: "{ 'hidBinaryFileIDs': '" + csList + "', 'userID' : '" + userID + "'}",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (data) {
    $.Zebra_Dialog(data.d, {
      'type': 'information',
      'title': 'Confirmation',
      'buttons': [{
        caption: 'Ok',
        callback: function () {

        }
      }]
    });
  },
  error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    $.Zebra_Dialog('Error : ' + xhr.status + ' - ' + xhr.statusText + ' : ' + thrownError, {
      'type': 'error',
      'title': 'Confirmation',
      'buttons': [{
        caption: 'Ok',
        callback: function () {}
      }]
    });
  }
});
```

When the ajax return success it displays the dialog box for a whole 2 seconds or so (not long enough for a user to read the message that it contains) then closes it. Using chrome's debugger, I've determined that it runs out of scope without waiting for a confirmation on the dialog box inside the success function. Does anyone know how I would go about halting the code until the user clicks ok?

Here is the full chunk of code for that ajax call..

```
 var leZDB = null;
    function zipSelectedAttachments() {

        var ids = getSelectedTaskIDs();
        if (ids.length > 0) {
            leZDB = $.Zebra_Dialog('Do you want to zip the attachment(s)?', {
                'type': 'question',
                'title': 'Confirmation',
                'buttons': ['Yes', 'No'],
                'onClose':function (caption) {
                    if(caption = 'Yes') {
                        LinkAndPass(ids);
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            $.Zebra_Dialog('No attachments are selected.', {
                'type': 'error',
                'title': 'Error',
                'buttons': [
                    { caption: 'Ok', callback: function () { } }

                ]
            });
        }
    }

    function LinkAndPass(ids) {
        leZDB.close();
        if (true)
        {
            SendIDSForZipping(ids);
        }
    }

    function SendIDSForZipping(ids) {
        var csList = '';
        var userID = $('#hiduserID').val();

        for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; ++i) {
            csList += ids[i] + ',';
        }
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.die('click');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            //async: true,
            url: "Notes/ViewAttachments.aspx/CompressFiles",
            data: "{ 'hidBinaryFileIDs': '" + csList + "', 'userID' : '" + userID+ "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            context:this,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                var hasClickedOK = false;
                var hasDisplayed = false;
                    if (!hasDisplayed) {
                        hasDisplayed = true;
                        $.Zebra_Dialog(data.d, {
                            'type': 'information',
                            'title': 'Confirmation',
                            'buttons': [
                                {
                                    caption: 'Ok',
                                    callback: function () {
                                        hasClickedOK = true;
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        });
                    }
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                $.Zebra_Dialog('Error : ' + xhr.status + ' - ' + xhr.statusText + ' : ' + thrownError, {
                    'type': 'error',
                    'title': 'Confirmation',
                    'buttons': [
                        {
                            caption: 'Ok',
                            callback: function () {
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

The getSelectedIDs() returns an array of numbers.

The Code behind returns a string.

Comment: If you halt the code, the user can't "Click Ok". It should be leaving the scope, what shouldn't be happening is the dialog should stay open until the OK button is clicked. This sounds like a problem with the `Zebra_Dialog` plugin or your implementation of it.

Comment: I've replaced the Zebra_Dialog box with alert(data.d) and it just loops alert boxes. I know for a fact that the function is only called once, as it only sends me one email on file completion.

Comment: If the alert happens more than once, then it is a fact that the function is being called more than once, which could also explain the odd behavior of the dialog.

Comment: Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j8KQF/) of your code. I can't see anything wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem consisted of the web method being called from the code behind. A faulty piece of logic caused it to refresh the page, instantly closing the box.

Answer (score 0):

try asyn:false in `$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  async: true
});`

Comment: still the same issue. I've commented it out of production for now, but it is rather annoying.